# Syntax highlighting not working by default for CSS

Tags: support, syntax-highlighting

Everytime I post CSS code on SO, I am slightly more annoyed by the incredibly incorrect syntax highlighting. So, I decided to make a post about it here. Every single other language has correct syntax highlighting, but CSS keeps getting problems.

According to [this thread](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/72082/246052), (if I am understanding this correctly), code is automatically highlighted based on its tags, with that whole list being the specific tags. Now, there's also a second list there with extensions to the specific tags, in which CSS is also listed. So, based on that, I'd assume CSS should work, as long as the CSS extension is indeed added.

Based on that, I assume questions that have [only the CSS tag](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21417272/1256925) should therefore also automatically get CSS highlighting for each of its answers. That is not the case, obviously (it's treating `#` as a comment, not an ID selector), so I'm wondering why. The [pastebin linked in the meta.SE post](http://pastebin.com/AWMtu5rK) also defines the CSS tag to `lang-css`.

So my question is, why do questions tagged with the [css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css) tag, even when that's the only tag on the question, not show CSS higlighting?

PS: I am tagging this as a bug, because based on what I know (and listed above), this should not be happening.

Comment: That looks like it answers my question. Should I remove the [bug] tag now? Or should I just leave it as it is?

Comment: @psubsee2003 well, those 2 links do explain pretty well why it was removed, so I think I have my explanation why it's not highlighting the text. Also, going by those links, I don't think it'll be reimplemented until the code higlighting is able to automatically detect CSS code, so I won't go for the feature-request.

Comment: @balpha I noticed syntax highlighting has been re-enabled on Stackoverflow, but it seems kinda random when the highlighting is applied. For example [this Q](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22381398/1256925) has the [html] and [css] tags and does have highlighted CSS, but [this Q](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21417272/1256925) has only the [css] tag and doesn't have highlighting. Do you have anything to do with this change in highlighting, and if so, could you please leave an answer to this post explaining?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This actually isn't a bug.  Originally, [css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css) did get CSS Syntax highlighting, but it was removed due to issues related to CSS questions commonly also having the [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) and [html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html) tags, and because of issues with Prettify not detecting CSS code blocks correctly.

For some background on the issue, you can review these questions from Meta.StackExchange

- [Do we auto-detect and highlight CSS for questions tagged CSS?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184781/do-we-auto-detect-and-highlight-css-for-questions-tagged-css)
- [What's happening to syntax highlighting for [css] questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121816/whats-happening-to-syntax-highlighting-for-css-questions)

However, you can still manually apply CSS highlighting to code.  You can get the details in [How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks),  but in short, the syntax is `<!-- language: lang-css -->`

Comment: `<!-- language: lang-css -->` doesn't seem to make it any different anymore. At least in the all-in-one CSS/JS/HTML widget output.

Comment: @D_N if it isn't working, I suggest posting a new question to ask if the functionality was changed.  i don't see a recent meta post asking about css syntax highlighting, so either it was recent or no one noticed it, or maybe there was another issue that caused it to not work

Comment: @ user241244   it seems to be `css` now, instead of `lang-css`