# Set the Code Language (used for syntax highlighting) for Swift tags

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tag-wiki, syntax-highlighting

At the bottom of each tag info page, there is a **Code Language (used for [syntax highlighting](https://github.com/google/code-prettify))**. This is something that can be changed by moderators.

Well, I'd like a few adjustments if possible:

- change [swift2](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/swift2/info) Code Language from `default` to `lang-swift`, because [4,053 questions are using it without the swift tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift2+-swift)
- change [swift3](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/swift3/info) Code Language from `default` to `lang-swift`, because [10,119 questions are using it without the swift tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift3+-swift)
- change [swift4](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/swift4/info) Code Language from *not set* to `lang-swift`, because [2,486 questions are using it without the swift tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift4+-swift)

<sup>Small reminder that we can still manually set the syntax highlighting language on each post with `<!-- language: lang-swift -->`.</sup>

Comment: The reason we don't have default highlighting turned on for CSS is documented [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256162/syntax-highlighting-not-working-by-default-for-css). `lang-yaml` and `lang-kotlin` don't exist, so they cannot be turned on. Not sure about the Swift tags. They very likely don't have highlighting because they are version-specific tags and thus aren't used alone. When combined with a [swift] tag, the highlighting will be as expected. I'm not sure if it would be harmful to add it to the version-specific tags anyway, though.

Comment: @CodyGray thanks for the link for CSS. Yet, it would be nice to have swift-lang for swift2, swift3, swift4. I'll make a separate request about adding yaml and kotlin. Edit: done at https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356979/add-google-code-prettify-support-for-yaml-and-kotlin

Comment: @Cœur note that SO uses the Google Prettify stuff, so if there's no `yaml` or `kotlin` available there, then it'll be a no go... See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274371/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work and the "How do I report a bug or request a new language?" section for reference

Comment: @CodyGray sometimes Swift2, Swift3, Swift4 are used alone. It would be nice to make the change for those.

Comment: Note, this request overrode previous changes from [Add syntax highlighting language 'default' for tags swift2.2 and swift3 (currently none)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321824/add-syntax-highlighting-language-default-for-tags-swift2-2-and-swift3-cur)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After the narrowing of this request, `lang-swift` has now been set for these three tags.