# Add Google Code-prettify support for YAML and Kotlin

Tags: feature-request, tag-wiki, syntax-highlighting

https://github.com/google/code-prettify supports *lang-yaml* and *lang-kotlin*, yet Stack Overflow currently does not.

**Can we add support for those syntax highlightings?**
<sup>(That would allow `<!-- language: lang-yaml -->` and `<!-- language: lang-kotlin -->`)</sup>

Afterwards:

- Change [yaml](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/yaml/info) Code Language from *not set* to `lang-yaml`
- Change [kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/kotlin/info) Code Language from *not set* to `lang-kotlin`

<sup>(That would allow `<!-- language: yaml -->` and `<!-- language: kotlin -->`)</sup>

[Edit]

Oh well,

- lang-yaml is a duplicate of [YAML highlighting doesn't work on StackExchange sites but is supported by Google Prettify](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/255968/yaml-highlighting-doesnt-work-on-stackexchange-sites-but-is-supported-by-google)
- lang-kotlin is a duplicate of [Support Kotlin in code highlighting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/299920/support-kotlin-in-code-highlighting) and **animuson** already rejected the request.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as duplicate of https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/299920/support-kotlin-in-code-highlighting

Comment: YAML is now done: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394321/add-code-prettifier-for-yaml-language-identifier