# Add code prettifier for YAML language identifier

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, syntax-highlighting

When will **YAML** language be supported in code blocks?

I come across more and more yaml language examples in Stack Overflow, especially for questions related to gitlab-ci configuration.

Example yaml code that should be prettified:

```yaml
job_name:
  script:
    - echo some command
```

There seem to be similar request [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356979/add-google-code-prettify-support-for-yaml-and-kotlin) (closed don't know why) or [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/255968/yaml-highlighting-doesnt-work-on-stackexchange-sites-but-is-supported-by-google) (no clear answer if this will be done or not).

Comment: The first is closed as it is both too broad (asking for two different languages) and because it was already covered by a meta.SE post asking for the same. The second post you found shows there has been a feature request for this on Meta.SE for quite some time now. New syntax highlighters requires the company to update the highlight.js version, something that's only rarely done.

Comment: Could you point to feature request you mentioned? I'd gladly upvote it if it is only way to get this feature on stackoverflow.

Comment: MSE FR: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/255968/yaml-highlighting-doesnt-work-on-stackexchange-sites-but-is-supported-by-google

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I kindly checked with a dev that is on the Q/A team if these kind of changes were considered low hanging fruit. There had been and there will always be performance considerations (both client and server-side as well us single user impact vs impact for the whole network) to take into account. Nevertheless, look what happened:

> I have added the syntax highlighting logic for YAML. It is now live (as you can see above).

All praise [Yaakov Ellis](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/344489/158100)

Comment: Now I need to look for every post where I used lang=none for YAML and correct it. It's going to be a long night.

Comment: @yivi I'm sorry. It was a long shot and I didn't assume it would get done this fast, if at all. I guess being positively surprised is the new standard ;)

Comment: Yeah, it was clearly tongue in cheek. It's great. Also, on the first post I could find with YAML I had already used "yaml" despite not being supported. Ahead of the times, I was.

Comment: If Yaakov keeps this up, I’m going to start confusing him with Oded. I like this new SE policy of “ask and ye shall receive”.